# Check if SQL object is referenced by any other SQL objects

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, dmv

I was just reading [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336840/accessing-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-stored-procedure-name-via-t-sql) and had a question for @Mack regarding whether there is a way to check if a SQL object is referenced by any other SQL objects.

He (@Mack) used T-SQL and DMVs to accomplish something similar in his answer.

Is this possible, if so how?

I would have posted this as a comment, but I don't have sufficient reputation yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but not with a DMV instead you'll need a related dynamic management *function*(DMF) `dm_sql_referencing_entities` (more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630351.aspx)).

Here is the code:

```
SELECT referencing_schema_name
     , referencing_entity_name
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('*schemaname.objectname*', 'OBJECT');
```

Here's a [link to the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188754.aspx) on DMVs and DMFs.