# How find deleted table fields in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to find stored procedures in my database which are not used anymore. So I thought maybe there is a way to find stored procedures or functions with deleted columns.

Thanks

Comment: Check below link if this will help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421439/tsql-query-to-find-un-used-stored-procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421439/tsql-query-to-find-un-used-stored-procedures)

Answer (score 0):

You need find dependence:

`sp_depends`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-depends-transact-sql

`dm_sql_referencing_entities` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referencing-entities-transact-sql

`sql_expression_dependencies` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql

```
EXEC sp_depends @objname = N'object name' ;  

SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME ( referencing_id ) AS referencing_schema_name,  
    OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) AS referencing_entity_name,   
    o.type_desc AS referencing_desciption,   
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referencing_id, referencing_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referencing_minor_id,   
    referencing_class_desc, referenced_class_desc,  
    referenced_server_name, referenced_database_name, referenced_schema_name,  
    referenced_entity_name,   
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referenced_id, referenced_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referenced_column_name,  
    is_caller_dependent, is_ambiguous  
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed  
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id  
WHERE referenced_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.object')
```