# Adding the postfix "_DELETE" to all stored procedures identified as not being used

Tags: sql-server

In attempting to clean up my database, I have managed to identity a list of stored procedures that aren't being used. I want to mark these for deletion, adding the post-fix "_DELETE" to all of these in one script. Can anyone advise me on how to go about this please? Thank you.

Comment: `EXEC sp_rename 'old_proc_name', 'old_proc_name_DELETED'`?

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595742/last-run-date-on-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server

Comment: Are these stored procedures not source controlled? If not, ask yourself seriously why they aren't. If yes, why not just plain delete them? Also, what do you want to do if the existing name's length > [`sysname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) length - 7?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use cursor for this purpose:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, SPName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
 ('old_proc_name1')
,('old_proc_name2')
,('old_proc_name3')

DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) = 'deleted'
DECLARE @newName VARCHAR(50)


DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT SPName FROM @mockupTable

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
      SET @newName = CONCAT(@name, '_DELETED')
      --PRINT @newname
      EXEC sp_rename @name, @newname
      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the names for your procedures you can just substitute them into your cursor definition below:

```
DECLARE ProcCursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT  Name = CONCAT(QUOTENAME(s.name), '.', QUOTENAME(p.name)),
            [NewName] = CONCAT(p.name, '_DELETE')
    FROM    sys.procedures AS p
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
                ON s.schema_id = p.schema_id
    WHERE   p.object_id IN 
            (   OBJECT_ID('dbo.SomeProc', 'P'),
                OBJECT_ID('dbo.SomeProc2', 'P'),
                OBJECT_ID('dbo.SomeProc3', 'P')
            );

DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(776), @NewName SYSNAME;
OPEN ProcCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM ProcCursor INTO @Name, @NewName
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    EXECUTE sp_rename @Name, @NewName, 'OBJECT';
    FETCH NEXT FROM ProcCursor INTO @Name, @NewName
END

CLOSE ProcCursor;
DEALLOCATE ProcCursor;
```

It is worth noting that this is one of the very few scenarios where I would advocate using a cursor, but as above when using a cursor you should always ensure you explicitly declare the simplest cursor possible (e.g. `LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY`). By telling SQL Server your cursor will be static, only used locally, and only ever read and only in one direction, your cursor will be much faster than if you don't and SQL Server has to work on the assumption that anything could happen with the cursor. On a small scale like this it is unlikely to make a tangible difference, but on larger sets it can make a considerable difference.

For further reading see [What impact can different cursor options have?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options) - The conclusion is actually that I should have used `LOCAL FAST_FORWARD`, rather than the options I did use. I have left these in though, as the difference is negligible and I found using all 4 easier to remember and displays intent clearer.

To re-iterate what has been stated in comments, it really is a good idea to use version control on your databases, that way you don't need to mark anything for deletion, you can just delete it, and still retain the definition in your source control. If you can't use source control for whatever reason, [DDL triggers can provide rudimentary change tracking](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/)